# Definition of first-order and second-order (quadratic) variation

Tags: probability, quadratic-variation

In Shreeve's book on finance in continuous time, he "defines" the following. He says on p. 99:

> In general, to compute the first-order variation of a function up to
> time $T$, we first choose a *partition* $\Pi= \{t_0, t_1, \ldots,
>  t_n\}$ of $[0,T]$, which is a set of times $0=t_0 < t_1 < \cdots <  t_n = T$. These will serve to determine the step size. We do not require the partition points $t_0 = 0, t_1, t_2, \ldots , t_n=T$ to be equally
> spaced, although they are allowed to be. The maximum step size of the
> partition will be denoted $||\Pi||= \max_{j=0, \ldots ,n-1} (t_{j+1} -
>  t_j)$. We then define  $$ FV_T (f) = \lim_{||\Pi||\to 0}
>  \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} | f(t_{j+1}) - f(t_j)|.$$
> The limit here is taken as the number $n$ of partition points goes to infinity and the  length of the longest subinterval $t_{j+1} - t_j $ goes to zero.

Unfortunately, these symbols (or rather their mathematical meaning) are not defined. It is unclear to me what this "$\lim_{||\Pi||\to 0}$" means. This is not a term defined anywhere in math. Also, given this "definition" (I put it in brackets because it really isn't a definition, as it doesn't define anything unambiguously), it is unclear why this would even exist.

Can someone give me a proper definition?

Further on, he goes on to "define" the notion of 'quadratic variation':

> **Definition.** Let $f(t)$ be a function defined for $0 \leq t \leq T$. The quadratic variation of $f$ up to time $T$ is  $$ [f,f] (T) =
>  \lim_{||\Pi||\to 0}  \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} ( f(t_{j+1}) - f(t_j))^2$$ where
> $\Pi= \{t_0, t_1, \ldots, t_n\}$ and $0=t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_n = T$.

Again, the meaning of the symbol is not defined (or defined properly), and I do not know what it means.

Thanks a lot in advance for clarifying.

Comment: I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#Formal_definition) can help

Comment: If you don't understand that symbol which Shreve defines in the same way like all other authors it might help to read Shreve's words following the limits.

Comment: @Marco Thank you.

Comment: @KurtG.That doesn't say anything--at least not anything mathematical. It is at most some vague intuition. Math is either unambiguous and clear, or it is not at all.

Comment: That same notation can be (and is) used to define Riemann or Riemann-Stieltjes integrals. Why do you blame Shreve about this? Why not the entire Riemann-Stieltjes literature?

Answer (score 3):

The limit as the mesh size goes to zero is quite standard when treating Riemann-Stieltjes integrals. The formal definition of $\lim_{\| \Pi \| \to 0}$ is the following:

---

Let $\Pi$ a partition of an interval $[a,b]$. and $\|\Pi\|$ as in the OP.

a sequence $X$ is called an evaluation sequence for a partition $P=\{a=:t_0< t_1 \cdots < t_n:=b\}$ if $X=\{x_1< \cdots <x_n\}$ with each $x_i \in [t_{j-1},t_j]$

Let $I(\Pi,X): \mathcal{P} \to \mathbb{R}$ a function (where $\mathcal{P}$ is the set of all the possible partitions over $[a,b]$).
$$
\lim_{\|\Pi\| \to 0} I(\Pi,X)=L
$$
if for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for any $\Pi \in \mathcal{P}$ such that $\|\Pi\|< \delta$ and for any evaluation sequence of $\Pi$ we have
$$
|I(\Pi,X)-L| < \epsilon
$$

Comment: Thank you very much.